# Why this message "You are not authorized to access this page." coming on user edit page?

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I am facing a strange behavior today, when I signup via Facebook or twitter and then go to user edit page it show this message:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

Even if try to access this page from admin login the same error is coming. 
But if in signup via email then everything working fine.

I am using these modules as well [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), [HybridAuth Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ohhhhh,* 
At last i figured it out. when i signup via Facebook or Twitter , user's language does not save and when i access the user edit page it gives error that you are authorized to access this page, 
and now i write my own function which set the default language for user and everything working like charm !!! thanks